# What is the best tools to find all the somatic mutations?

Tags: phylogenetics, variant-calling, gatk, maftools

I am a beginner in this field. I would like to know which is the best way to get all the mutations from a certain sample. At this point, I am considering using GATK ([here](https://gatk.broadinstitute.org/hc/en-us)) and Maftools ([here](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/maftools/inst/doc/maftools.html#1_Introduction)). I don't know which method is better, or are there any other better tools you would recommend?

Comment: MAFtools is not a variant calling tool. Google "benchmark somatic variant callers" and read some papers - MuTect2, SomaticSniper, VarScan2, Strelka etc are some relevant tools.

Comment: What organism are you working on, i.e. your sample? This has an enormous impact on the approach and the tools.